# sidebar not displaying when using get data

Tags: sidebar

I have a sidebar as a widget which displays correctly on all pages depeneding on the super page id. I am using a custom function to calculate and display the required sidebar.

```
    function is_tree($pid) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post;
    $postId = null;
    $ancestors = array();

    if(count($post)>1){
        $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
        $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
        //print_r($post);
        switch($cat[0]->name){
            case "Press Release":
                $postId = PAGE_ABOUT;
                break;
            default:
                $postId = "00000";
                break;
        }
        if($post->post_type == "event")
            $postId = PAGE_ABOUT;
        if($post->post_type == "technical_paper")
            $postId = PAGE_GEOLOGICAL;

    }else{
        $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
        if(isset($cat[0])){
            switch($cat[0]->name){
                case "Press Release":
                    $postId = PAGE_ABOUT;
                    break;
                case "Technical Paper":
                    $postId = PAGE_GEOLOGICAL;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($post){
        if($post->post_type == "job_listing")
            $postId = PAGE_CAREER;
        if($post->post_type == "event")
            $postId = PAGE_ABOUT;
        if($post->post_type == "technical_paper")
            $postId = PAGE_GEOLOGICAL;

        $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->$pid);
        $root = count($ancestors) - 1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    }   

    if( is_page() && (is_page($pid) || $post->post_parent == $pid || in_array($pid, $ancestors)) || ($pid == $postId) )
        return true;
    elseif( 5581 == $pid && $_REQUEST['ir'] )
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Using [widget logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin i called this function on each different sidebar using `is_tree(pid)`.

If you browse to following page the sidebar will show https://gateway.spectrumasa.com:10443/investors/investor-news/news-room/investor-news-story however with get data if you browse to the following page it does not.

https://gateway.spectrumasa.com:10443/investors/investor-news/news-room/investor-news-story?ir=http://cws.huginonline.com/S/139450/PR/201411/1873983.xml.

How can i solve this problem. I use the same method for the right sidebar.

The content is being displayed using a shortcode, which takes the get data and parses the xml file to produce the output.

```
if(!require_once("MagicParser.php")){
  echo "Please contact Support";

}else{

    $ir_url = $_GET['ir'];    
    $filename = $ir_url;
}


  function myRecordHandler4($record)
  {
    print "<b>".$record["BODY/PRESS_RELEASES/PRESS_RELEASE/HEADLINE"]."</b> (";  
    print $record["BODY/PRESS_RELEASES/PRESS_RELEASE/PUBLISHED-DATE"].")";
    $tmp = $record["BODY/PRESS_RELEASES/PRESS_RELEASE/MAIN"];
    $tmp = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$tmp);
    $tmp = str_replace("please contact:","please contact:<br/>",$tmp);
    $tmp = str_replace("Olset","Olset<br/>",$tmp);
    $tmp = str_replace("Spectrum ASA","Spectrum ASA<br/>",$tmp);
    $tmp = str_replace("49 65","49 65<br/>",$tmp);


    print $tmp."<br />";
    //print str_replace("&nbsp;","",$record["BODY/PRESS_RELEASES/PRESS_RELEASE/MAIN"])."<br />";
  }

  function pageInvestmentResultA($record)
  {
    print "<a target='_new' href='".$record["LOCATION-HREF"]."'><b>".$record["FILE_HEADLINE"]."</b></a> ".$record["FILE-FORMAT"]."<br />";
  }
  if(!$filename)
    echo "No content found!";
  else{    
    MagicParser_parse($filename,"myRecordHandler4","xml|HEXML/");
    MagicParser_parse($filename,"pageInvestmentResultA","xml|HEXML/BODY/PRESS_RELEASES/PRESS_RELEASE/FILES/FILE/");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

wordpress did not like the file extension. use substring to remove file extension and then add it back in later.